# How Can i save the converted jpg image to a specific directory?

Tags: php

the following code is saving the converted jpg file to the home directory like where the code is placed i want to store it in a folder namely images.
the file dcm-to-jpg is the file that i am executing on the web browser and then all the functions are being called. basically this is a dicom to jpg converter the solution i want is to save the converted file to a new folder that i have already created and also do let me know how to change the name of the file is that possible too??
Thanks in advance!! :)

```
Filename = dcm-to-jpg.php
<?PHP
#
# Creates a jpeg and jpeg thumbnail of a DICOM file 
#

require_once('../class_dicom.php');

$file = (isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : 'image1.dcm');

if(!$file) {
  print "USAGE: ./dcm_to_jpg.php <FILE>\n";
  exit;
}

if(!file_exists($file)) {
  print "$file: does not exist\n";
  exit;
}

$job_start = time();

$d = new dicom_convert;
$d->file = $file;
$d->dcm_to_jpg();



system("ls -lsh $file*");

$job_end = time();
$job_time = $job_end - $job_start;
print "Created JPEG and thumbnail in $job_time seconds.\n";


?>



filename = class_dicom.php
### Convert a DICOM image to JPEG. $this->file is the filename of the image.
### $this->jpg_quality is an optional value (0-100) that'll set the quality of the JPEG produced
  function dcm_to_jpg() {

    $filesize = 0;

    $this->jpg_file = $this->file . '.jpg';
   
    $convert_cmd = BIN_DCMJ2PNM . " +oj +Jq " . $this->jpg_quality . " --use-window 1 \"" . $this->file . "\" \"" . $this->jpg_file . "\"";
    $out = Execute($convert_cmd);

    if(file_exists($this->jpg_file)) {
      $filesize = filesize($this->jpg_file);
    }

    if($filesize < 1) {
      $convert_cmd = BIN_DCMJ2PNM . " +Wm +oj +Jq " . $this->jpg_quality . " \"" . $this->file . "\" \"" . $this->jpg_file . "\"";
      $out = Execute($convert_cmd);
    }

    return($this->jpg_file);

  }
?>
```

Comment: Add the folder name to your command: `$convert_cmd = BIN_DCMJ2PNM . " +oj +Jq " . $this->jpg_quality . " --use-window 1 \"" . $this->file . "\" \"images/" . $this->jpg_file . "\"";`

Comment: the folder name is images can you please change the code and write here!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My example puts `images/` in front of the JPG filename, which should give you what you need.

Comment: i have changed the command but still it is not sending the image to that directory!! either now it not even creating the file in the directory where the code is!!

Comment: @kmoser Any Solution??

Comment: Please show an example of what the exact command should be to create the output file in the `images` folder.